# If a spring is connected to a block and the other end is fixed, what's the force on the object after releasing the spring from a stretched position?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, spring

A spring is connected to a block and the other end of the spring is fixed, if the block is pulled with a hand, thus stretching the spring, what would be the force applied to the block once the hand releases the block? I am aware of Hooke's law where force=kk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an ideal, massless spring, Hooke's Law applies regardless of whether the block is moving or not. In particular, the force at the instant after you let go is the same as in the instant before you let go because the extension of the spring is the same before and after.